# Prove that the function is constant

Tags: real-analysis

> Let $f:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a differentiable function such that for all $x\in\mathbb{R}^2$, 
>   $$
> \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_2}(x)=2\cdot\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1}(x).
> $$ 
>   Prove that for every $c\in\mathbb{R}$ function $f$ is constant on $$M_c=\left\{x\in\mathbb{R}^2: 2x_2+x_1=c\right\}.$$

I don't know how to approach.

Comment: is there a minus sign missing somewhere?

Comment: @Thomas, I checked. The task is well-prescribed.

Comment: Approach : Over the set $M_c$, show that the partial derivative w.r.t $x_1$ is zero. Hint : Find a relationship between partial derivative w.r.t $x_1$ and partial derivative w.r.t $x_2$ that is satisfied over the set $M_c$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider the map $\phi \colon \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^2$ defined by
$$
\phi(t) = \begin{pmatrix}
c-2t \\
t \end{pmatrix}.
$$
Now try to compute
$$
\frac{d}{dt}\left( f\circ \phi \right) = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1} \cdot (-2) + \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_2}
$$
and use the assumption. What can you conclude from this?

Comment: Ok, finally I see it. With this parameterization we have that $\phi: \mathbb{R}\rightarrow M_c$ so we need to prove that $(f\circ\phi)$ is a constant function. But by chain rule $\frac{d}{dt}(f\circ\phi)=-2\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_2}=0$ (assumptions) so the derivative is equal to zero, so the function is constant. Beautiful, thank you so much again!

Answer (score 1):

Note that by the given assumption the gradient of $f$ is orthogonal to $\mathbf{d}=(2,-1)$ at any point $\mathbf{x}$ in the domain of $f$, i.e. $\nabla{f(\mathbf{x})}\cdot{\mathbf{d}}=0$ all $\mathbf{x}\in\mathbb{R^n}$ Now use the mean value theorem in several variables which states that for a differentiable function $f:\mathbb{R}^n\mapsto\mathbb{R} $  for every $\mathbf{a},\mathbf{b}\in \mathbb{R^n}$ there is a $\mathbf{c} \in [\mathbf{a},\mathbf{b}]$, where  $$[\mathbf{a},\mathbf{b}]:=\{\mathbf{x}\in  \mathbb{R^n}| \mathbf{x}=t\mathbf{a}+(1-t)\mathbf{b},  t \in [0,1]\subset \mathbb{R}\}$$
such that $f(\mathbf{a})-f(\mathbf{b})=\nabla{f(\mathbf{c})\cdot{}(\mathbf{a}-\mathbf{b})}$.

Now pick a point $\mathbf{a}=(a_1,a_2) \in M_c$, and let $\mathbf{b}=(b_1,b_2)\in M_c$ be arbitrary. Then clearly $\mathbf{a}=(c-2a_2,a_2)$ and $\mathbf{b}=(c-2b_2,b_2)$. From the mean value theorem above it follows that $f(\mathbf{a})-f(\mathbf{b})=\nabla{f(\mathbf{c})}\cdot(\mathbf{a}-\mathbf{b})=\nabla{f(\mathbf{c})}\cdot{}(2,-1)(b_2-a_2)=(b_2-a_2)\nabla{f(\mathbf{c})}\cdot \mathbf{d}=0$.

Comment: This method is instructive, but it requires an additional assumption, namely:  $f$ has $C^2$ class (existence and continuity of the partial derivatives of second order)

Comment: @Mohamed I think that it is enough that f is differentiable,  have a look at these notes for example : http://matrixeditions.com/VC.Chap1.148-149.pdf

Comment: I am sorry I had a stupid confusion between the symbols $\nabla$ and $\Delta$ (Laplacian). I hope that a moderator removes the last part of my comment above : "but it requires ..." till the end  and  replace  by  :  " I keep it as an excellent alternative "

Answer (score 0):

Well! we  can  generalize this :
$f$  is  constant on  all   subset  $M_{u,v,I}$ of  $\mathbb R^2$ where :$$M_{u,v,I}=\{(u(t),v(t)) \mid   t  \in  I  \}$$   where : $I$  is  an  open intervall  and  $u,v$  having   $C^1$ class   on  $I$   to  $\mathbb R$  such  that :  $u' + 2  v'=0$

In  our  example we   have  :  $I=\mathbb R$  and  $u(t)=t$  and  $v(t)=\frac{c-t}2$